# ASP.NET MVC свой HtmlHelper + Partial

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Доброго дня, друзья! Тщательно готовился перед тем как задать вопрос. И вот.

Задача такая - есть часто повторяемый код вёрстки (сам код специально упрощён, на деле там много всего из-за чего и встал, собственно, вопрос более грамотной реализации). Хочется сделать подобный Partial View:

```
<div id="{IDENT}">
@RenderBody
</div>
```

У нас есть IDENT (идентификатор) и какое-то тело. Чтобы далее в какой-либо другой View вызывать нечто подобное:

```
@using(Html.DrawMyCustomSection("ident12345"))
{
<b>Передать в тело</b>
}
```

Чтобы на выходе иметь:

```
<div id="ident12345">
<b>Передать в тело</b>
</div>
```

Вопрос в самой "элегантности" решения. Самый простой способ - отказаться от Partial View вообще и рендерить всё средствами `MvcHtmlString`. Но это, сдаётся мне, моветон и я его не рассматриваю, как достойный вариант.

Второй способ - использовать кастомный хелпер с реализацией IDisposable и рендерингом PartialView с заменой контрольных строк `{IDENT}` и `{BODY}` на своё. Этот вариант вроде как лучше, но ненамного :)

Третий способ - строготипизированная модель для PartialView, в которой всё передавать. Хороший способ, как по мне. Но не могу понять как правильно передать само тело в PartialView и как там его разворачивать.

Также можно накрутить реализации с `ViewBag` / `ViewData`, но это совсем плохо.

Отсюда вопрос: Как **правильно**, **грамотно** и **красиво** передать в PartialView параметры и отрендерить тело в основное представление? Использовать строготипизированную модель, тогда как в неё записать (получить) то, что было в основной вьюшке указано в теле?

Буду рад любому ответу и\или примеру. Спасибо!

Comment: Не работаю с `ASP`, но приятно видеть грамотно оформленные вопросы. Так держать!

Comment: @Other спасибо! Просто сам знаю как могут раздражать вопросы, ответы на которые лежат на первой странице гугла :) Жаль, что пока ответов нет(

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понял, вам требуется создать аналог `@using(Html.BegibForm())`. Т.о. будет возможность оборачивать в `div` с заданным `id` другую `razor` разметку.

Для этого потребуется создать класс или добавить в существующий новый html helper (зависит от того как вы их храните).

Далее пример для отдельного класса:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyWebApplication.Helpers
{
    public static class UserIdentityHelper
    {
        private const string TagName = "div";

        private class UserIdentityContainer : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly TextWriter _writer;

            public UserIdentityContainer(TextWriter writer)
            {
                _writer = writer;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                var builder = new TagBuilder(TagName);
                _writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
            }
        }

        public static IDisposable UserIdentity(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string userIdentifier)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder(TagName);
            builder.Attributes.Add("id", userIdentifier);

            var writer = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer;
            writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

            return new UserIdentityContainer(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Не забудьте добавить в `web.config` новый `namespace` (если еще не добавлено):

```
<namespaces>
  ...
  <add namespace="MyWebApplication.Helpers" />
  ...
</namespaces>
```

Вызов будет выглядеть, например, так

```
@using (Html.UserIdentity("ident12345"))
{
    <h1>Hello ident12345!</h1>
}
```

И в результате будет получена разметка следующего вида:

```
<div id="ident12345">
    <h1>Hello ident12345!</h1>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что вызов `UserIdentity` возвращает класс, который реализует `IDisposable`, а закрывающий тэг создается с параметром `TagRenderMode.EndTag`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ и время, которое я у вас занимаю. Но вопрос именно в вставке razor в другую `PartialView`. Т.е. не генерировать тег через `TagBuilder`, а брать `PartialView` и в него вставлять наше тело + идентификатор. Ваш метод отлично подходит, но я хотел бы отказаться от генерации HTML кода и использовать `PartialView`, как шаблон. Такое возможно?

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не до конца понял вопрос. Такой задачи пока не встречал, нужно подумать как реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется именно для подобных целей и был создан View Component

1. Создаем класс с названием нового компонента

   ```
   [ViewComponent]
   public class ShowIdent
   {
       public string Invoke(string idParam, string textParam)
       {
           return $"<div id=\"{idParam}\"><b>{textParam}</b></div>";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Вызываем в нужной вьюхе

   ```
   @await Component.InvokeAsync("ShowIdent", new { idParam = "ident12345", textParam = "Передать в тело"})
   ```

Более подробно о View Component тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/7.6.php